# Error in: org.geotools.swing.MapLayerTableCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent

Tags: java, error, geotools

Getting this error while exporting an shapefile to svg (courtesy to iant):

The weird thing is I wasn't getting this error before, but I just suddenly starting getting it after running my application, what could have happened?

Code can be found here: [Exporting Shapefile to SVG using Java & GeoTools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166121/exporting-shapefile-to-svg-using-java-geotools)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.geotools.swing.MapLayerTableCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(MapLayerTableCellRenderer.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:208)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:779)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1055)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5232)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1529)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1452)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5180)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4991)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: @iant any ideas? still happening