# Map display issues when exporting to SVG with Geotools

Tags: java, geotools

I am using geotools to display a map, convert the map coordinates to screen coordinates, and export it back out as an SVG file. So far everything works fine, however I have run into two issues I could use assistance with. (Note: I cannot display any maps I am using due to confidentiality agreements)

1. Some lines on the map, after conversion, are missing (segments and whole lines).
2. The map is inverted (upside down).

The bigger issue is the first one, but I am not sure what is causing it (no errors or exceptions). Could be line conversion code or loading the map. I will post my line conversion code and my attempt to correct the inverted code.

Also the map is based in Michigan, which could be causing this issue (I am not a map/geotools expert).

```
    // Converts map lines to fit in smaller window (mainly for Adobe Illustrator)
    private ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertLines(ArrayList<FeatureLine> lines) {

    ArrayList<FeatureLine> convertedCoords = new ArrayList();

    try {
        Rectangle imageBounds = jFrame.getBounds();
        ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = map.getMaxBounds();
        AffineTransform world2screen = createTransform(mapBounds, imageBounds);


        for (FeatureLine coord : lines) {
            Point2D screenCoordStart = world2screen.transform(coord.StartPoint, null);
            Point2D screenCoordEnd = world2screen.transform(coord.EndPoint, null);


            if (coord.StartPoint.x != 0.0) {
                convertedCoords.add(new FeatureLine(screenCoordStart, screenCoordEnd));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occured while converting lines", ex);
    }

    return convertedCoords;
}
```

Inverts map

```
//Invert map to look normal (doesnt work).
System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");
```

This could work, but I'm not sure where to use the CRS

```
// Inverts map
Hints hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
            CRSAuthorityFactory factory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", hints);
            CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326");
```

Loading the map

```
// Load shapefile into JMapFrame
    protected void loadFile(File shapeFile) throws IOException {

        URL shape = shapeFile.toURI().toURL();
        ShapefileDataStore ds = null;

        try {
            FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shape);
            featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

            ds = new ShapefileDataStore(shape);
            FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fs = ds.getFeatureSource();

            Hints hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
            CRSAuthorityFactory factory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", hints);
            CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = factory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326");

            collection = fs.getFeatures();
            featureArrayS = featuresList();

            map = new MapContent();
            Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
            //Style style = createStyle(shape, featureSource);

            Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
            map.addLayer(layer);

            System.out.println("File name: " + shapeFile.getName());
            jframe.setTitle("File: " + shapeFile.getName());

            String layerName = "Default";

            layer.setTitle(layerName);
            layerList.add(layer);

            jframe.setMapContent(map);

        } catch (IOException | FactoryRegistryException | FactoryException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", ex);
        } finally {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an example to explain [Michigan's CRS](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/DNR_Map_Proj_and_MI_Georef_Info_20889_7.pdf).

**Update: 3/31/2017**
This one shows the inverted output of the map, the inverted map being on the left, while the correct (and desired) output is on the right.
[image: Inverted Output/Correct Display]

This shows a zoomed in picture of the missing lines, incorrect output on the left, and correct (expected) output on the right.

[image: Zoomed in missing lines & expected output]

Here is the CRS for the map:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Natural_Origin", 
  GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983", 
    DATUM["D_North_American_1983", 
      SPHEROID["GRS_1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]], 
  PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator"], 
  PARAMETER["longitude_of_center", -86.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_center", 45.30916666666666], 
  PARAMETER["azimuth", 337.25555999999995], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 2546731.496], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", -4354009.816], 
  PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle", 337.25555999999995], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH]]
```

Lastly, I obtained this map data from [here](http://www.mcgi.state.mi.us/mgdl/?rel=ext&action=sext):

Comment: I assume you are building on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166121/exporting-shapefile-to-svg-using-java-geotools - if so is the map the right way up on the screen? the ForceXY will only fix 90 deg rotations not inversion which is probably to do with SVG having it's 0,0 origin in the **top** left corner

Comment: Yes I am (that is an older version, but the base is still similar), and I believe you are correct, its flipped horizontally 180 degrees, not 90 degrees. I also know about the different [origin](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/affinetransform.html) as well, but what i can't figure out is how to implement a working solution. I used to use a (-1,-1) translation on the SVG, but that started to cause some issues.

Comment: group.setAttributeNS(svgNS, "transform", "scale(1, -1)"); this is what I used to flip it.

Comment: I still need help with this error, primarily the missing lines, I have a way around the flipped map that its not urgent. I still can't seem to figure out the missing line problem. Could really use some help/advice on this matter.

Comment: @iant any ideas? I used QGIS to convert the maps, which worked well, however if i use any maps with points in them, it fails completely (which is the most important part). Also the maps of QGIS and mine are not aligned, they are off a bit (so I can't combine them).

Comment: I can't really add to previous answers - I pointed you to working svg export code and you kept going in another direction. I do sell support if you really need help

Comment: The export code you gave me didn't work, I had a similar export code (from the geotools tutorial) and it gave me slanted lines. I need to be able to convert the lines one by one and export it, so that doesn't help me. Also the primary issues is maps in the michigan area, any other maps usually work fine. How would your 'support' be any different?

Comment: the code I pointed to works fine - I just tested it on a world shp file. My support would involve looking at your exact problem and shapefile to see what is the issue

Comment: Did you test it with a michigan map? that's the only issue that I'm having:
 [Michigan Maps](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/DNR_Map_Proj_and_MI_Georef_Info_20889_7.pdf)
Some example maps, I used the 'state roads' map.

Comment: Also this explains the problem: [Michigan CRS](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/DNR_Map_Proj_and_MI_Georef_Info_20889_7.pdf)